# HTML scraping using R - Error scraping particular node

Tags: r, web-scraping, data-science

I am trying to web scrape job descriptions from the webpage -https://www.indeed.com/cmp/HP/jobs

I am also new to scraping using HTML and CSS selectors so I apologize if I'm doing something stupid.

I have the following code

```
test_url <- read_html("https://www.indeed.com/cmp/HP/jobs")
  job_description <- test_url %>% 
    html_nodes(".cmp-JobDetailDescription") %>%
    html_text()
```

I used the CSS selector to find the node but for some reason I cannot get the job descriptions.

What do I have to change in my code to extract all the job descriptions in that url?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have a look instead at the APIs documentation: http://opensource.indeedeng.io/api-documentation/

Comment: The page makes xhr requests for indiv descriptions e.g. https://www.indeed.com/cmp/_/job?jk=5d91456037b5a832&tk=1dtp0a4inq4ms800&onlyLog=1  where I suspect part of the url is an id present on the original page.Scraping is against T&Cs hence my suggestion to look into API

Comment: Ohh i see, thank you :)